# How to implement pocketsphinx with windows 7 and eclipse ?Or how to use java sphinx speech recognition to android?

Tags: android, speech-recognition, offline, sphinx4

I want To use sphinx 4 speech recognition in android.Recently I used sphinx4 speech recognition for java and implemented successfully.

But my problem is pockesphinx is speech recognition for android.I could not understand the tutorial.I tried so many times to run the pocketsphinx but could not succeed,as I don't know about Linux commands,and I want to implement pocketsphinx with the eclipse Helios and my OS is windows 7.Can anyone give me some steps to implement the pocketsphinx with windows 7 and eclipse for android.Its been a two weeks now that I just visiting the tutorial but nothing I can make it.So please.Can anyone help me out.Or even if there is any things like I can import my sphinx4 speech recognition of java to android application??because I tried even implement the code of sphinx4 java to android but its not working at all?

Comment: Hi, found that post because I got the same problems. Have You fixed it?

Comment: oh man, this is a really hard task with sphinx. My opinion is, that the tutorial on CMU Sphinx website is not really good described. However, if I will be sucessfull, I would let You know....

Comment: thanx..i have worked for month...then i left out ...if u find this then pls knw me...thanx

Comment: I will post my solution here on this question....I hope I can get one....

Comment: Can we implement the same thing by using Recognizer the google api

Comment: i dont know... never heard abt that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To run it on windows, follow the instructions found here:

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialpocketsphinx#windows

Then you can run pocketsphinx_continuous to test it, for example:

`pocketsphinx_continuous.exe 
 -hmm {pocketsphinx path}\model\hmm\en_US\hub4wsj_sc_8k 
 -dict {pocketsphinx path}\model\lm\en_US\cmu07a.dic 
 -lm {pocketsphinx path}\model\lm\en_US\wsj0vp.5000.DMP`

I created a blog post about this: http://mariangemarcano.blogspot.dk/2012/09/speech-recognition-with-pocketsphinx.html

Answer (score 1):

The Problem with windows and this tutorial is, that it could be very different in some steps to systems like windows or the android version. I had access to build the PocketSphinxAndroidDeo, which is using pocketsphinx, not sphinx4. I don´t know if it is possible to integrate sphinx4 into an android project, I read some posts where the poeple say it isn´t. But with pocketshinx, I had for now success to get the Demo work, maybe it could help, give it a try and read what I have done:

https://sites.google.com/site/opiatefuchs/home/pocketsphinxandroiddemo

Comment: thank you.....i dont know..but very few poeple have knowledge on this...need to w8 more then 6 or 7 months to get help..